# A gpload control file processing error occurred. Entry must be a YAML sequence

Tags: database, load, greenplum

I want to load data into a greenplum database with gpload.py (Windows Server). But I only get a weird output:

> |ERROR|A gload control file processing error occured. The gpload:input:source(1):file entry must be a YAML sequence

I tried to use gpload with linux and it worked fine. So my yaml file and my input data should be correct.

Does anyone know how to fix that problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should post the yaml config file you are using to make sure there are no other problems.  But I would guess since you said that it works on linux but not on windows that you have a line ending problem.

YAML files are line and whitespace sensitive.  Try editing the file with a local editor on the Windows machine.